# Is there any special relationship between numbers divisble by 3, 4, 5 and 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I admit this is a weird question, since it concerns a fragment of a book by an eccentric Finnish author. I would like to figure out whether this fragment does make any mathematical sense or is a total rubbish.

The author described a city in which houses are on purpose numbered only with numbers divisible by 3, 4, 5 an 7 and this is presumably due to the fact that "7 is the holy number and the numbering (I guess the author refers to the numbering of the houses) uses its various foundations and derivatives".

My guess is that the above fragment is a total gibberish and have nothing in common with real mathematics. Maybe it has something to do with numerology, but I could not find anything related in this topic as well so far. So I will be really grateful if anybody could assure me that the fragment I quoted is really mathematically meaningless.

EDIT.

The original book I am referring to is: **Daniel Katz, Herra Lootin tyttäret, 1999, p. 263**.

And this is the original passage I am refering to (the last sentence is the most important):

*Katujen nimet muuttuvat kesken kaiken ja eri puolilla katua voi olla eri nimet. Numerotkin heittävät uskomattomasti. Täällä meillä on käytössä parillis-pariton-systeemin lisäksi kolmella jaolliset luvut ja neljällä, viidellä, jopa seitsemällä jaolliset, sillä seitsemän on somoralaisten pyhä luku ja niinpä seitsemän eri fundamentit ja niistä johdetut luvut ovat myös käytössä talojen numeroimisessa.*

So I hope this will enable someone with command of Finnish language to provide a decisive answer to the question.

Comment: Seems you are not physically in Finland  at this time. Perhaps you could edit in the title and author and page number for this fragment, one of the moderators is Finnish (and some of the other users) and perhaps someone can comment on this author. There is nothing mathematical about the suggestion that 7 is the holy number; many cultures have lucky or unlucky numbers, sometimes with religious aspects as well.

Comment: The integers divisible by $3, 4, 5$ and $7$ are those divisible by the least common multiple of $3, 4, 5$ and $7$, namely $420$.  Is that what you're asking about, or is it the "holy" nonsense?

Comment: 7 remind me of the movie *seven* starring Brad Pitt and Morgan Freeman, the movie have some holy connections though, and one more thing, there are seven sins:-P as far as 420 is concerned, it is used for thieves and bad people in India :-)

Comment: I guess that this may have something to do with jewish Kaballah since the author is a Finnish Jew. 

Anyway, I will soon provide original Finnish title, edition and page number so we can try to get a decisive answer to this question.

Comment: Must the numbers be divisible by *all* of 3, 4, 5 and 7, or by any of them? You get a lot more numbers the second way.

Comment: That's a good question, which I have unfortunately no answer for as it is not clear from the context.

Comment: I don't know if that's the origin, but the numbers $7$ and $12$ are prevalent in Christian context (7 cardinal sins, 7 sacraments; 12 apostles). Also the numbers $3$ and $4$ are special (trinity; 4 gospels), and they are intimately related to $7$ and $12$: $3+4=7$ and $3\times 4=12$. I never heard about the number $5$ being considered special, but $5=12-7$. However I don't see how you would get there starting *only* from $7$, without the $12$. After all, you could also say $7=2+5$, $2\times 5=10$, $10-7=3$, and thus use all multiples of $2,3,5,7$. Or $7=1+6$, covering all multiples of $1$.

Comment: Much as I enjoy fiction with a mathematical theme, I'm voting to close.  Apart from observing that there is [something special about every whole number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox), it is unclear what question is being asked that might be on-topic here.

Comment: I agree with that. Sorry for being ambiguous, but this is due to the ambiguity in the actual text. Thus, I agree it is okay to close the question now.